# Internal Error 500: Hosting our latest Laravel 5.1 site on good working Vagrant/Homestead environment

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

**Configuration Development system**

- Laravel 5.1
- Good working Vagrant/homestead on windows 10.
- V1 Production Laravel site working on Vagrant/homestead (non-responsive)
- V2 production Laravel **NOT** working on Vagrant/homestead (responsive)

The Steps to narrow the problem:

**Part 1 – The basics**

1. Import SQL file with PhpMyAdmin
2. I have added or changed all the  necessary steps (URL, homestead.yaml, hostfile ect)
3. I have a Working fresh Laravel 5.1 installation

**Part – 2 The Migration**

1. Imported a new database with phpMyAdmin
2. Removed the fresh installation
3. Copy the new “production environment”
4. Changed the .env file with the required database information
5. Load site and BAM an Laravel error “Houston we have got a problem Internal 500 message”

**Part – 3 Done so far fixing the problem**

1. Artisan clear cache will make it worse
2. Removed everything and installed a fresh 5.1 Laravel environment
3. Copy the folders 1 by one and when I copy the APP directory it will result in an “Internal error 500”

ERROR and LOG
[image]

**Part – 4 Conclusion**

We have a good working vagrant/homestead environment and it goes wrong when I am migrating the new production site to this configuration. The difference between V1 and V2 is that V1 (working on vagrant/homestead) is a **non-responsive** site and V2 is the same site but completely responsive.

Any tips on how to solve this issue

Comment: I think you should check the laravel log file to see the exact error message, so you know exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: Oh man, thank you.
I forgot to add this to step 3..Will add this today..

Comment: Purge the `bootstrap/cache` directory and restart `php-fpm` if you're using  it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on: "Artisan clear cache will make it worse"... How so? "V2 production Laravel NOT working"... How so, e.g. does it show an error page and what does it say? If it's always a 500, then what is the cause for it (check your app logs). Can you "tail -f" your laravel log and paste what the output is when you try to access your v2 site.

Comment: Added the log file.

Comment: Have you done a `composer install`?

Comment: Yes I did that and it works fine `composer create-project laravel/laravel responsive "5.1.*"` and I get the Laravel logo screen.

Comment: Oke to be clear! When I have finished a fresh installation of Laravel by using composer I copy all my production Laravel files over the existing fresh installation and then I change the .env file. Please let me know if this is not the right way.

Comment: I deepdive the logs and I am seeing Vagrant is using the directories of my production servers ;-( 
`(/home/xxx/www.domainname.com/releases/20170713122151/storage/framework/: `

I think if I know where this is stored in Laravel then I have the solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By deepdiving more in the log files I have finally fixed the issue.

Only removing the vendor directory wasn't enough you must also remove the .lock file.

**Solution:**

1. Remove the **vendor** directory
2. Remove the  **composer.lock** file
3. Run `composer update -v`

Answer (score 0):

check the env file
you may have forgotten to create the env file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32846828)